# Regex: Make search and replace up to a certain point (up to a certain line from paragraph)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

So, I have this text. I need to use regex as to change the word **however,** and replace it with **(empty space)**

The big problem is that I want to make the replacement in all text, but only those occurrences before the paragraph that starts with **Creation of the**.

So, I don't want to replace nothing after the starting point **Creation of the**, only in the text lines before it.

> Since, in theory, the contract is reason, the notion of an irrational
> contract could be labeled an oxymoron. The factual reality proves,
> however, that more than 90% of the purchases we make as consumers are
> irrational.
>
> We contract out of fear, out of servile imitation, under the impact of
> the hallo effect, under the pressure of authority[1], we buy because
> that's what the "community values" impose on us, we buy into rules or
> customs (however absurd) because we need to signal our virtue, etc.
>
> With or without awareness of this fact, however, our consent can be
> manufactured, and our will can be channeled, through mechanisms that
> trigger emotional or stereotyped (oligo-rational) reactions.
>
> But the manufacturing of consent[2], the channeling of will and
> irrational or oligo-rational contracts are already obsolete - today's
> man "acquires" obligations from automatisms of algorithms, from
> non-contracts[3].
>
> **Creation of the** technological creature, the non-contract is a combination of algorithms and automatic mechanisms intended (i) to
> induce, however, implicit legal effects, as a result of presumptions
> of acceptance of the terms and conditions imposed by the digital
> platform or by the social network or by the "cookie" collector ” and
> (ii) extract from us our behavioral surplus.
>
> Driven by the "need" for better behavioral prediction and the
> neutralization of risk and uncertainty generated by human agency and
> free will, however, non-contractuality becomes overwhelming within the
> digitized economy.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bhowever\b(?=.+Creation of the)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b                      # word boundary
however                 # literally
\b                      # word boundary
(?=.+Creation of the)   # positive lookahead, make sure we have "Creation of the" somewhere after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: great answer, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ I suggest to search for "Creation of the", select the text from just before this to the beginning and limit the search & replace to the selection by using the check box next to the "replace all" button.

[image]

---

If you have the command line program `awk`, you can use something like

```
awk '/Creation of the/ { skip=1 } !skip { gsub(/however/,"") } 1' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `/Creation of the/ { skip=1 }` = set flag to skip substitution when pattern is found
- `!skip { gsub(/however/,"") }` = if flag is not set, substitute
- `1` = always-true condition with empty action which defaults to `print`
  (The `1` could be replaced with `{ print }`.)

Comment: thanks, but your answer works only for 1 single file. But if I want to make a replacement into 150 file, simultaneous, will not work ;)

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu You get answers based on the requirements in your question. That's why it is important to write *all* requirements.